# Concurrent hashmap size() method complexity

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

I'm wondering if the `size()` method invoked on `ConcurrentHashMap` is of the same complexity as the `size()` method for usual HashMap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't. In my version of the JDK, `HashMap.size()` has `O(1)` complexity, whereas `ConcurrentHashMap.size()` *in the best case* has to iterate over the segments. In the worst case it will lock all segments, which can be a pretty expensive operation in a multithreaded scenario.

Of course, which is *faster* is a different question altogether. The answer largely depends on how many threads are accessing the map, and what it is exactly that they are doing.

Comment: I've found that in JDK 8, this is no longer true. See my answer somewhere else on this page (or [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22996395/1268003)).

Answer (score 9):

The new implementation of [ConcurrentHashMap.size()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#size--) in **JDK 8** uses a cool algorithm they kind of copy pasted from [LongAdder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html).

In effect, the complexity of `ConcurrentHashMap.size()` is almost constant ("O(1)" in nerd language) and the real time cost as compared with `HashMap.size()` is negligible. Don't believe me? Open my basic [test project](https://github.com/MartinanderssonDotcom/concurrent-hashmap-size-cost) and have a run yourself. I don't have JDK 7 installed on my current machine, it would be cool to get feedback on time cost with Java 1.7 as compared with Java 1.8.

Comment: Interesting find, Martin!

Answer (score 5):

The complexity of `size()` on `HashMap` is `O(1)`, because the size is stored in a field. If we look at the implementation of `size()` on `ConcurrentHashMap`, we see, that it is bigger (> O(1))

**Reference (openjdk-6)**

- [HashMap#size()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.size%28%29)
- [ConcurrentHashMap#size()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#ConcurrentHashMap.size%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of the size() method in the ConcurrentHashMap is essentially an O(N) operation (varying mainly with the number of segments) as you can see in the source.  HashMap is an O(1) operation.

```
/**
 * Returns the number of key-value mappings in this map.  If the
 * map contains more than <tt>Integer.MAX_VALUE</tt> elements, returns
 * <tt>Integer.MAX_VALUE</tt>.
 *
 * @return the number of key-value mappings in this map
 */
public int size() {
    final Segment<K,V>[] segments = this.segments;
    long sum = 0;
    long check = 0;
    int[] mc = new int[segments.length];
    // Try a few times to get accurate count. On failure due to
    // continuous async changes in table, resort to locking.
    for (int k = 0; k < RETRIES_BEFORE_LOCK; ++k) {
        check = 0;
        sum = 0;
        int mcsum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < segments.length; ++i) {
            sum += segments[i].count;
            mcsum += mc[i] = segments[i].modCount;
        }
        if (mcsum != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < segments.length; ++i) {
                check += segments[i].count;
                if (mc[i] != segments[i].modCount) {
                    check = -1; // force retry
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (check == sum)
            break;
    }
    if (check != sum) { // Resort to locking all segments
        sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < segments.length; ++i)
            segments[i].lock();
        for (int i = 0; i < segments.length; ++i)
            sum += segments[i].count;
        for (int i = 0; i < segments.length; ++i)
            segments[i].unlock();
    }
    if (sum > Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    else
        return (int)sum;
}
```

Comment: This does not really help. Could you remove the longish sourcecode snippet and instead tell us why the map is split into multiple segments and how many segments we can expect to find? We'll get O(N) complexity only if the number of segments is a constant fraction of N.

Answer (score 0):

This is an irrelevant question as calling size() on a concurrently mutable structure is an essentially pointless thing to do. All it will ever tell you is what the size *was* and you cannot actually do anything with this information apart from maybe log it.

If you try and use size() without locking the structure you will have race conditions.